# Same network, Two devices can't ping each other

Tags: windows, networking, ping

We have one AT&T Router on our home network.  The following devices and IPs are what I'm working with:

- Desktop PC (192.168.1.86)(Minecraft) Usage: Minecraft Server
- Laptop 1 (192.168.1.85)(SKDT) Usage: Minecraft client, Node.js Server
- Android Phone (192.168.1.83)(Android (numbers)) Usage: Ping Test app.
- Laptop 2 (unknown)(Ronan) Usage: Minecraft client
- Router (192.168.1.254)() Usage: Router
- Google (8.8.8.8)() Usage: Test WAN connectivity.  Also using google search works just as well.

Laptop#2, Ronan, will connect to Minecraft from the LAN.  Unfortunately, I cannot charge it at the moment, so I can't figure out what settings it has.  Laptop#1, SKDT, will connect to Minecraft from the WAN, but not from the LAN.  I downloaded a ping test app on my phone to test the settings.

Phone Pings:

- Minecraft: Yes.
- Google: Yes.
- SKDT: Yes.
- Router: Yes.

SKDT Pings:

- Minecraft: `Request timed out.`
  Occasionally `Reply from 192.168.1.85: Destination Host Unreachable` as the third out of four packets sent.
- Router: Yes.
- Google: Yes.
- Phone: Yes.

Minecraft Pings:

- Router: Yes.
- Google: Yes.
- Phone: Yes.
- SKDT: `Request timed out.`

Things I've heard suggested:

- Firewall: It's not the firewall.  I can turn the firewall off entirely for SKDT and Minecraft and the problem persists.
- Client Isolation: It's not that... My cell phone can connect to the server.  My cell phone can connect to my laptop.  Unless isolation can occur between just two computers, and not for the whole LAN, this doesn't work.
- And... I'm out of ideas.

So yeah, it's just two computers that won't connect to each other, even though they will connect to the same other devices.  And, I should note, laptop#2, Ronan, had the external WAN ip for our network as the IP address for the MC server.  On laptop#1, SKDT, I have tried both the remote and local IP's, with and without the `:25565` default MC port number, and no combinations of that work.

Our Router is through AT&T Uverse, Minecraft is on Windows7, SKDT is Windows10.

Comment: I don't get this part `Laptop#1, SKDT, will connect to Minecraft from the WAN, but not from the LAN`. Why is it listed as LAN device if it's not in the LAN but coming through your router's WAN interface?

Comment: It's a laptop. I can connect to the server when I'm on my Grandma's WiFi, but not when I'm on our home WiFi where the server is.  I did not check the ping stuff when out on the WAN because I had no reason to because everything was functional then.

Comment: Can you verify that you don't have rules configured on your firewall for Laptop#1, such as DHCP IP reservations. Also, do some ping replies time out from phone/Laptop#2 to your minecraft server when your Laptop1 and Minecraft server are running and connected to your LAN?

Comment: No pings time out between the phone and the other devices.  I cannot test things with laptop#2.  As for rules on the firewall, like I said, the problem persists even when I disable the firewalls on both computers.

Comment: OK. It sounds like you're trying to ping a device that is behind a NAT from the wan. This is not possible. If you could explain how the network is setup, it would help a ton. Are your grandma wifi a different network? Different house? Just because both PC's are on the same subnet won't mean they can ping each other even if they are on separate networks. Unless you use a VPN.

Comment: It also sounds like you need to port forward the server through the router in order to connect via wan

Comment: It is port forwarded.  Anything coming into the router from the WAN, with the 25565 port goes to the desktop Minecraft on the same port.  My grandma's WiFi is entirely separate, in another city, under a different AT&T account.  I set the server and ports up with my brother while I was at my grandma's and he was home.  And we were both able to access the server from our respective laptops, so I thought there was no problem.  I came home this week and haven't been able to connect.  Upon experiencing this, I started ping tests, and discovered the weird results posted in the question.

Comment: Our home network is a simple subnet.  Mask 255.255.255.0, local IP range 192.168.1.x, The only isolation-related setting I can find is opening up a second 'Guest' internet login, which we do not use.  All computers and devices besides the router should be at mostly the same level.  Desktop Minecraft has ethernet.  Phone and laptops all are WiFi.

Comment: Does SKDT's ARP table contain the correct MAC address to IP address mapping for "Minecraft"? How about vice-versa? If the answer to one or both is "no", what happens if you enter correct static ARP mappings?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late but this was exactly the problem in my case. 2 computers (also a wired and a wireless one) could not ping each other, although they belong to the same network, while other computers could ping both of them.

Spiff's comment gave me a hint:

> Does SKDT's ARP table contain the correct MAC address to IP address mapping for "Minecraft"? How about vice-versa? If the answer to one or both is "no", what happens if you enter correct static ARP mappings?

I checked the ARP table with the command `arp -a` on both computers, to see if the other one's IP is there and then deleted them with the command `arp -d <IP>`.

**The problem was that the wrong MAC address was cached and the computers could no longer communicate.**

After further investigation, I discovered that on the laptop I had switched from wireless to wired and that's probably where things got messed up, although the wired IP was different.

So, in your case, on Minecraft you should run `arp -d <SKDT IP>` and on SKDT `arp -d <Minecraft IP>`. Then, on their next attempt to find each other, they will re-learn each other's MAC address.