# Why can't I ping a computer in same network?

Tags: lan, ping, icmp

I have two computers on the same Wifi router. I want to ping the other one, it does not happen, I get a "destination host unreachable".

Things I've already tried:

I disabled the Firewall on both computers

I tried to ping myself on both computers, I get a reply

I capture the traffic in Wireshark, I can capture the ICMP packets that pinging some outside address like 8.8.8.8, when I ping the other computer or myself, Wireshark does not capture this.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Some additional information.

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.1, Dst: 192.168.0.131
Internet Control Message Protocol
    Type: 3 (Destination unreachable)
    Code: 3 (Port unreachable)
    Checksum: 0x7f07 [correct]
    [Checksum Status: Good]
    Unused: 00000000
    Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.131, Dst: 192.168.0.1
        0100 .... = Version: 4
        .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
        Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        Total Length: 56
        Identification: 0x2c37 (11319)
        Flags: 0x0000
        Time to live: 128
        Protocol: UDP (17)
        Header checksum: 0x8ca9 [validation disabled]
        [Header checksum status: Unverified]
        Source: 192.168.0.131
        Destination: 192.168.0.1
    User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 63998, Dst Port: 2054
    Data (28 bytes)
```

Like I said before I do not capture the ICMP messages when I send the ping request. I did capture some ICMP communication between router and PC, I added the message above if it is of any help to anyone.

Comment: Similar question here....https://superuser.com/questions/1177305/same-network-two-devices-cant-ping-each-other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't ping other machines in my network](https://superuser.com/questions/125052/cant-ping-other-machines-in-my-network)

Comment: the Problem is more or less the same, but the answers do not help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your WiFi router may have a *Wireless Isolation* option enabled, which prohibits communication between wireless clients, described here in detail:

https://www.howtogeek.com/179089/lock-down-your-wi-fi-network-with-your-routers-wireless-isolation-option/

Comment: I connected to the router and checked this and it was not the case the isolation is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other replies in the linked posts help you, try looking into this: [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49652-turn-off-network-discovery-windows-10-a.html)

Whenever you first connect to a network on Windows, you get a popup asking you if you want to detect for other devices on the network. If you answer "No", Windows Firewall will block all connection attempts from other devices on the network - even ICMP packets like ping.

Comment: That would cause "Timed out", but not "Destination host unreachable" – the latter shows up when the host doesn't even answer ARP queries, which is something an ordinary firewall would not block.

Comment: When I try to ping, I do not capture any ARP queries in Wireshark. Otherwise I can see ARP queries being send from the router and being answered as well.